# use timeit inside a function

Tags: python, time, timeit

Say I want to test two heap implementations like this:

```
def test_heap():
    for i in range(15):
        test_list = random.sample(range(10000), 1000)
        print(timeit("h = heap1(test_list)", "setup"))
        print(timeit("h = heap2(test_list)", "setup"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_heap()
```

I don't want to put whatever is in `test_heap` into the main, what should the setup statement be so I can import `test_list` into `timeit`?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the names you need are apparently globals. (At least, I assume that they are because they aren't shown.) You can just import those from `__main__`.

```
 "from __main__ import heap1, heap2"
```

`test_list` is tougher. You can get it from your function's `locals()`, but that's not available inside `timeit()`. Probably easiest thing to do in this case, since it's just a list of integers, is to construct a string version of the list and have Python evaluate it.

```
"test_list = %r" % test_list
```

(This wouldn't work so well if you had e.g. object instances.)

Put them together with a semicolon and you get the following setup string:

```
 "from __main__ import heap1, heap2; test_list = %r" % test_list
```

(also, remember to close your parentheses)

Comment: The problem here is that `test_list` is local, and the questioner explicitly doesn't want to make it global. You can't import it.

Comment: so I can only import global variables?

Comment: Only global variables are in `__main__`. You can get the local variables otherwise, however. I'll edit.